# Running a child component with a function in parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

so i have two components a Child "Board.js" that bring an array from backend and build a Board it looks like this:

```
const Board = (props) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const newBoard = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/viergewinnt/newboard')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // console.log(data);
            return data
        })

    const arr =[];
    data.map(d => arr.push([...d]))
    console.log(arr);
    setData(arr);
}

return (

    <div className='center'>
        <div className='board'>
            { data.map((d) => d.map((v, index) => (<BoardTile  key ={index}/>)))}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
```

and a parent component "NewGame" which has a button, this button when clicked must build that board in child component. The Parent component looks like this:

```
const NewGame =  (props) => {

const onClickHandler = () =>{
    return (<Board></Board>)
}

return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>
            <button className='btn' onClick={onClickHandler}>Start new game</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

PS. the Board was built successfully when all the code was in one Component.

Comment: Any particular reason that your Start New Game button is in parent component?

Comment: separation of Work, learning how :), and making sure to keep my code clean somehow

Comment: I assume you are exporting your Board component and importing it in NewGame?

Comment: Also, where is your <Board/> getting rendered inside of the App? You are returning from onClickHandler, but this isn't anywhere inside the main render method.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Board from './example.js';
import { useState } from 'react';

const NewGame = (props) => {
  const [boardIsVisible, setBoardIsVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>
        <button 
          className='btn' 
          onClick={() => setBoardIsVisible(true)}>
           Start new game
        </button>

        {boardIsVisible && <Board />}
       </div>
    </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i am getting these errors

***react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

***index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: also Another thing...every time the button is clicked=> the function newBoard must be triggerd(and it's in the Child component)

Comment: You need to actually run the newBoard function after declaring it, like so: newBoard(); - you might also try wrapping this in a useEffect() so it runs it once on mount - `useEffect(() => { newBoard(); },[]);`